# Merge multiple csv files where it contains a mix of headers and no headers

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have multiple csv files in a directory, however, the csv files are mixed, some of it contains headers, some do not have headers. (for eg, file_01.csv, file_02.csv, file_03.csv, file_04.csv)

Is there efficient shell script method to merge all csv files together, with the first the row containing the header?

Once merging, I intended to de-duplicate it to remove duplicate rows in that merged csv file.

Here is an example

```
For eg. file01.csv #got header
name, dob, gender, date_of_enrolment
John, 11-06-01, M, 20-01-2020
Beth, 12-03-01, F, 20-01-2020 

For eg. file02.csv #no header
John, 11-06-01, M, 20-01-2020
Mary, 13-01-01, F, 20-02-2020

For eg. file03.csv #got header 
name, dob, gender, date_of_enrolment
Mary, 13-01-01, F, 20-02-2020
David, 13-02-02, M, 20-03-2020

desired output merged_file.csv
name, dob, gender, date_of_enrolment
John, 11-06-01, M, 20-01-2020
Beth, 12-03-01, F, 20-01-2020
Mary, 13-01-01, F, 20-02-2020
David, 13-02-02, M, 20-03-2020
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Do you have a way to tell if a given file has a header row or not?

Comment: You can do all of this with Miller (mlr), but you will have to separate previously the ones that have header from the ones that have no header.

Comment: hi all, thanks for replying, please find attached above an example

Answer (score 2):

If you make sure the first csv file read in **does** have a header, you can just do this:

```
shopt -s extglob; awk '!seen[$0]++' file01.csv file!(01).csv
```

*Note* that the above assumes you are using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and `file01.csv` has a header

If you don't want to worry about file order, you can do this, but note that it does create two memory copies for each line -- this is necessary to preserve order

```
  awk '
   !/name,/ && !seen[$0]++ {
      s = s sep $0
      sep=ORS
   }

   /name,/{h=$0}
   END{print h ORS s}' file*.csv
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ awk '
       !/name,/ && !seen[$0]++ {
          s = s sep $0
          sep=ORS
       }

       /name,/{h=$0}
       END{print h ORS s}' file*.csv

name, dob, gender, date_of_enrolment
John, 11-06-01, M, 20-01-2020
Beth, 12-03-01, F, 20-01-2020
Mary, 13-01-01, F, 20-02-2020
David, 13-02-02, M, 20-03-2020
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about if the first csv file does not have a header,  how do i go about it?

Comment: hi thanks, when you have time, appreciate if you can explain how does it work

Comment: `!seen[$0]++` is an idiom that only returns true when a line ($0) has been seen for the very first time.  After the first time, the counter increments above zero and taking the negation of a non-zero number is zero, and therefore false.

Comment: Tried your suggestion, received a memory overload fatal error, not sure why. Maybe a better way will be to load the csv files into a temp sql table and then select distinct from temp?

Comment: After thinking a bit about it, this is the best solution. There is only a single problem I notice. You store the files twice in memory (first time in `seen` second time in `s`). If the order of the records do not matter, you can do: `/name,/{h=$0;next}{a[$0]++}END{print h; for(i in a) print i}`

Comment: @kvantour I updated the answer to do what I think is the best of both worlds.  As long as you make sure the first file has a header, you don't need to worry about all the line manipulations to put it at the top.  But if you have tons of csv files, you probably don't want to type those out either.  With the use of the `!( )` extglob you can specify a file with a header (any file) and then have the rest be wildcard'd in.

Comment: very nice. I agree

Answer (score 2):

With GNU grep:

```
cat file*.csv | grep -m 1 ^name; grep -vh ^name file*.csv | sort -u
```

Comment: Need to pipe to `sort -u`to remove dupes

Comment: @SiegeX: Thank you. I missed that. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This is a great short version, however if you have a lot of files and by accident only the last file has a header, then this will be a bit slow.

Comment: You don't need to cat to the first grep just like you don't cat to the second grep.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

- Merging the files into one .csv:

```
cat file0{1..4}.csv > merge.csv
```

- De-duplicate rows (and keep headers in the first line of the file):

```
sort -r merge.csv |uniq > output.csv
```

Then, the `output.csv` file would look like this:

```
name, dob, gender, date_of_enrolment
Mary, 13-01-01, F, 20-02-2020
John, 11-06-01, M, 20-01-2020
David, 13-02-02, M, 20-03-2020
Beth, 12-03-01, F, 20-01-2020
```

Comment: You use `sort -r` to cleverly ensure that the header is on top. But what you give is not a definitive answer. What if one of the records contains a name that does not start with a captial letter (a typo).

Comment: The trick in this case is not about capital letters but about alphabetical order. And yeah, it is not a universal solution valid for every case, but only for the scenario described in this single question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{print /[0-9]/,$0}' file* | sort -k1,1n -uk2 | cut -d' ' -f2-
name, dob, gender, date_of_enrolment
Beth, 12-03-01, F, 20-01-2020
David, 13-02-02, M, 20-03-2020
John, 11-06-01, M, 20-01-2020
Mary, 13-01-01, F, 20-02-2020
```

The above prepends a column to indicate the type of each line (header is 0, other is 1) then sorts on that column first to get the header at the top, then sorts on the original lines and then removes the extra column we added in step 1. Since only `sort` has to handle all of the input at once and it's designed to use paging, etc. to handle large files, that should work even if your input files are massive plus it'll be very fast to execute.

Here's the steps:

```
$ awk '{print /[0-9]/,$0}' file*
0 name, dob, gender, date_of_enrolment
1 John, 11-06-01, M, 20-01-2020
1 Beth, 12-03-01, F, 20-01-2020
1 John, 11-06-01, M, 20-01-2020
1 Mary, 13-01-01, F, 20-02-2020
0 name, dob, gender, date_of_enrolment
1 Mary, 13-01-01, F, 20-02-2020
1 David, 13-02-02, M, 20-03-2020

$ awk '{print /[0-9]/,$0}' file* | sort -k1,1n -uk2
0 name, dob, gender, date_of_enrolment
1 Beth, 12-03-01, F, 20-01-2020
1 David, 13-02-02, M, 20-03-2020
1 John, 11-06-01, M, 20-01-2020
1 Mary, 13-01-01, F, 20-02-2020

$ awk '{print /[0-9]/,$0}' file* | sort -k1,1n -uk2 | cut -d' ' -f2-
name, dob, gender, date_of_enrolment
Beth, 12-03-01, F, 20-01-2020
David, 13-02-02, M, 20-03-2020
John, 11-06-01, M, 20-01-2020
Mary, 13-01-01, F, 20-02-2020
```

The above is just a minor adjustment to the idiomatic way to sort input but retain the header at the top:

```
awk '{print FNR>1,$0}' file* | sort -k1,1n -k2 | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

The only significant difference is using `/[0-9]/` instead of `FNR>1` to separate the header line. If `/[0-9]/` isn't adequate to match only/all your non-header lines then use whatever is, e.g. maybe `!/^name/`.